# Asp.net core get all files from azure cloud blob segment

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-blob-storage

Using asp.net core return all file names from azure cloud blob storage. In blob storage their are many sub folders. In each sub folder their are around 20 k to 25 k files. On passing the sub folder name it should return all the file names in that particular folder. I am using the below code to retrieve the files

```
   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                    CloudStorageAccount.Parse(configuration["ConnectionStrings:AzureStorageConnectionString"]);
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("portal");

var blobResultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("SubFolder",
                    true, BlobListingDetails.All, int.MaxValue, null, null, null);
var totalFiles =blobResultSegment.Results;
```

The above code is not returning all files form that particular folder. Is their any best way to get all file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan to recursively loop through all data in the container sub path, you can use something like this

```
public async Task FindByStation(string patternMatch)
        {
            string nextMarker = null;
            var continuationToken = new BlobContinuationToken
            {
                NextMarker = nextMarker,
            };
            var results = new List<IListBlobItem>();

            BlobResultSegment blobResultSegment;

            while (continuationToken != null)
            {
                blobResultSegment = await _blobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(patternMatch,
                   true, BlobListingDetails.All, null, continuationToken, null, null);
                continuationToken = blobResultSegment.ContinuationToken;
                results.AddRange(blobResultSegment.Results);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ListBlobsSegmentedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobssegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobsSegmentedAsync_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_System_Nullable_System_Int32__Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobContinuationToken_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_OperationContext_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method only return a result segment containing the blob prefix. And if you want to list the blob name you need loop the result to get it.

You could refer to the below code.

```
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");

            var blobResultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("testfolder",true, BlobListingDetails.All, int.MaxValue, null, null, null);

            var totalFiles = blobResultSegment.Results;
            foreach(CloudBlob file in totalFiles) {
                Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
            }
```

And remember blob doesn't have folder, it's a virtual path, it's just the blob with a prefix `foldername/blobname`. If you want to the get all blob in a subfolder, the best is set the prefix with `foldername/`. Or it will list the blob name like the below pic.

[image]